# Replace multiple "select" with for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE tab_1 (
    t1 decimal (10),
    t2 decimal (10),
    t3 decimal (10)
);

INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1, t2, t3) VALUES ( 1, -2, -5);
INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1, t2, t3) VALUES (-3,  4,  6);
INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1, t2, t3) VALUES ( 5,  1,  2);


SELECT sum(t1) FROM tab_1 WHERE t1 > 0;
SELECT sum(t2) FROM tab_1 WHERE t2 > 0;
SELECT sum(t2) FROM tab_1 WHERE t3 > 0;`
```

I have a query like above and i need a script that can replace the three `select` with a `for i=1:3`

The output must be like:

> Q_total:
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> 8

Thank you !

I use MYSQL Workbench 6.3.7

Comment: You want three results or one? I mean do you want one select for that?

Comment: I want one select for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `PREPARE statement`

```
SET @sql := '';
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT SUM(',COLUMN_NAME,') FROM tab_1 WHERE ',COLUMN_NAME, ' > 0' SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='your_database_name'
AND TABLE_NAME ='your_table_name';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

Comment: I've try but it doesn't work, i think i make something wrong

Comment: I've updated the answer to indicate where should u put the database name and table name

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this in a function?  The results you're looking for can be given from a single query.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t1 > 0 THEN t1 ELSE 0 END) AS t1Sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2 > 0 THEN t2 ELSE 0 END) AS t2Sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t3 > 0 THEN t3 ELSE 0 END) AS t3Sum
FROM tab_1
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to do manualy because, in this exemple i have only t1,t2,t3 but when i have t1 to t50 or t50000, how can i do?

Comment: Dont create a table with **columns** t1 to t50000. Instead treat those column headings as code values in **A** code column and have the associated value in another column and have **many rows** instead of many columns.  Then you dont need a loop,  just a simple group by query.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, in this exemple i create the table but in my personal case I don't create it, the table is imported from excel, with max 50 columns, and i don't want to edit it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `Procedure` for this

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC()

BEGIN
  DECLARE a INT Default 1 ;
  simple_loop: LOOP         
     SELECT sum(t@a) FROM tab_@a WHERE t@a > 0;
     SET a=a+1;
     IF a=4 THEN
        LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;
 END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
```

To call that stored procedure use

```
CALL `ABC`()
```

Comment: Why isn't `a` declared as a `decimal` type?

Comment: `INT` is for whole numbers; `DECIMAL` is for numbers with decimal digits.

Comment: This answer is half way there.  You actually have to construct, via `CONCAT()`, the `SELECT` and use `prepare` and `execute` statements.  Such a mess.  You would be better off doing it in your client language (PHP/Java/VB/...).

Comment: I can't figure out how can i write this query to work. I've tried with concat(), also instead of 'tab_@a' i put 'tab_1' but was no succes.